# pseudo-abelian category / Karoubian category in K-theory

Tags: homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, algebraic-k-theory

A pseudo-abelian category or Karoubian category $\mathcal{C}$ is a preaditive
category such that every idempotent morphism
$i: A \to A$ in $\mathcal{C}$ has a kernel and consequently a
cokernel as well.

Moreover the Karoubi or preudo-abelian completion
associates to an arbitrary preadditive category
$\mathcal{D}$ a pseudo-abelian category $Kar(\mathcal{D})$
called the pseudo-abelian completion or Karoubian envelope of $\mathcal{D}$
[Here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Karoubian+category#examples)
is is shortly noted unfortunately without any references that pseudo-abelian completion
is also used in the construction of the category of pure motives, and in K-theory.

I found heaps of materials on how it is used in the
construction of the category of pure motives but almost nothing
about it's importance in K-theory.

Can somebody give an overview of how the pseudo-abelian completion
takes important part in K-theory.

Comment: I think it only has an effect in K_0

Comment: When you say $K_0$ do you refer to concrete algebraic
$K$-theory $K_0(A)$ ($A$ ring) or is your $K_0$  
imposed in general setting for arbitrary
stable $(\infty,1)$-category?

I know that since finitely generated projective $A$ modules
arise as Karoubian completion of fin.gen. free $A$ modules
and $K_0(A)$ is nothing else than 
finitely generated projective $A$ modules modulo 
isomorphism classes, one may say that 
$K_0(A)$ indeed "involves" the Karoubian completion. Is 
this the only situation where Karoubian completion
is used in construction of $K_0$?

Comment: Or does the Karoubian completion have an effect on the
$K_0$ in general setting, ie 
for every stable $(\infty,1)$-category?

Comment: It is not just $K_0$? it is the negative ones also? In arXiv:0903.3717 we find the statement: The reason for this is that negative K-theory is, in particular, an obstruction for the (triangulated) quotients to be Karoubian.

Comment: I don't remember the name of the theorem. I could look it up but have no time right now. It's a theorem, if I'm not too mistaken, that idempotent completion only changes K_0.

Comment: @WilberdvanderKallen thanks for setting me straight. I guess my memories come from connective Waldhausen K-theory.

Comment: @FernandoMuro: So on the relation of negative $K$-groups to the property of beeing Karoubian almost everything is said. Could you explain when you have a little more time how the idempotent completion involved explicitely the in construction of $K_0$?