# construction of $K_0$-group and Karoubian completion

Tags: homotopy-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-k-theory, triangulated-categories

Let $A$ be a ring. The $K_0$ group of $A$ can be defined in most
old fashioned way as the Grothendieck group of the set of isomorphism classes
of its finitely generated projective $R$ modules, regarded as a monoid under direct sum.

One can show that this $K_0(R)$ coincides with Quillen-construction
$K_0(P_A) := \pi_1(BQ(P_A),0)$ if $P_A$  is the category of finitely generated projective A-modules. The important issue of Q-construction is that it associates $K_i$ groups to every
[exact category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_category). In more general setting applying  [S-construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waldhausen_category#S-construction)
one can associate $K$-theory groups to categories with cofibrations (called
Waldhausen categories).

If we go back to the first construction of $K_0(R)$ we observe that the
auxilary category $P_A$  of finitely generated projective A-modules is formally
the  [*Karoubi or preudo-abelian completion*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Karoubian%20category#karoubi_envelope) of the category $F_A$ of finitely generated free $A$-modules.
What we see is that the preudo-abelian completion or preudo-abelian categories play
somehow a central role for the definition of algebraic $K_0(R)$ group.

My question is how concretely is the pseudo-abelian completion involved in the
construction of $K_0$ group in more general setting like in Quillen's construction
or S-construction if we start with an arbitrary exact or Waldhausen category $\mathcal{C}$.

One could also ask if this definition of $K_0(A)$ in algebraic $K$-theory
involving pseudo-abelian completion of fin.gen. free $A$-modules is something
special what happens only in construction of algebraic (and topological due to Swan's theorem) $K$-theory or
is the pseudo-abelian completion here based on a deeper more general principle
used in construction of $K_0$ in $K$-theories in general setting?

The question is closely related to [this discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403220/pseudo-abelian-category-karoubian-category-in-k-theory) that mostly uncovers the
obstructional relation between existence of nonzero negative $K$-groups
and Karoubian completeness of underlying category.
Now I would like to understand if and how the pseudo-abelian completion is
involved in construction of $K_0$.

Comment: You can also define the $K$-theory of $F_A$, it's just less interesting in general (as it is always a cyclic group). The higher $K$-groups agree with the usual one. So I would say the Karoubi completion is not conceptually important to define $K$-theory, it's conceptually important because we like projective modules

Comment: hm, I'm still not 100 percent convinced that the procedure of 
Karoubi completion is "expendable" for constructions 
in $K$-theory in general setting. 
Do you have an idea which constructions from $K$-theory are referred to here:

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Karoubian+category#examples ?

Comment: None of the notions of $K$-theory that I know require Karoubian completion ( I may be missing some, but I'm thinking of group completion $K$-theory, the $K$-theory of an exact ($\infty$-)category, and the $K$-theory of a stable $\infty$-category) . In fact $K$-theory detects dense subcategories (see Thomason, "classification of triangulated subcategories") and so is particularly well suited to study non Karoubian closed things

Comment: So the ring is $A$ or $R$?

Comment: In fact the famous cofinality theorem relates the K-theory of a Waldhausen category and of its Karoubian completion (and, as Maxime is saying, tells you that the map is injective on $\pi_0$ and an isomorphism on higher groups). Therefore Karoubian completion is relevant only for the 0-th group.